# getenv() not working

Tags: java, ubuntu-10.04, netbeans-6.9, getenv

I've created a stand alone a java application in Ubuntu 10.04 using Netbeans 6.9. I'm not able to use use the getenv() command in Netbeans, though if i create a separate java file in gedit and compile it in the terminal then it gives the desired output.

```
System.out.println(System.getenv("TRGRAPH"));
```

The above code when executed through the terminal gives the desired output but the same code if i try to run in Netbeans then it returns a null string.
Can anyone tell me how to get the output using netbeans??

Comment: [Check this link out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243581/using-getenv-function-in-linux)

Comment: Check this link for configuring environment variables while running the program in NetBeans
http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqEnvVarsDuringRun

Answer (score 2):

You need to launch Netbeans from the **same** terminal **after** you have set and exported TRGRAPH.

Example, in a terminal:

```
$ export TRGRAPH=foo
$ netbeans&
```

Comment: what if I run the jar file of my application, then also it is giving null.

Comment: how are you running it? through netbeans?

Comment: I was running it using netbeans but when i run the .jar file separately then also I m getting the same problem..

Answer (score 1):

I use Eclipse, not NetBeans, but I bet they are similar.  Look for a dialog that controls how your program gets launched. This dialog probably has a place where you can specify environment variables that should be set when your app is launched.

The other alternative is to set the environment variable before you launch Netbeans.

Answer (score 1):

It means that TRGRAPH is not defined in the process. The environment gets inherited from the environment of Netbeans. Make sure, that Netbeans gets the variable, e.g., by starting it from a command line or by invoking it using a shell script *sourcing* your `.bashrc` (or wherever you define TRGRAPH).

---

Alternatively, you can start an external Java process using the `ProcessBuilder` and pass it any environment you like. Quite complicated, but very flexible.